# Pandas/Numpy - Fill Missing Values Per Another Column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Good afternoon all i have a dataframe

dataframe = df

```
NPI       Fa Name
1100      
1100      Johnson
1100  
5555 
2222      Meghan
2222    
4444
4444
```

My goal is to fill in the Missing FA name per the corresponding NPI if it is present

```
    NPI       Fa Name
    1100      Johnson
    1100      Johnson
    1100      Johnson
    5555 
    2222      Meghan
    2222      Meghan
    4444
    4444
```

i know this might be a simple task, however coding wise i am having trouble figuring it out. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with forward and back filling missing values if order is important:

```
#if necessary
df['Fa Name'] = df['Fa Name'].replace('', np.nan)

df['Fa Name'] = df.groupby('NPI')['Fa Name'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
print (df)
    NPI  Fa Name
0  1100  Johnson
1  1100  Johnson
2  1100  Johnson
3  5555      NaN
4  2222   Meghan
5  2222   Meghan
6  4444      NaN
7  4444      NaN
```

If not, fist sorting per both columns and then use [`GroupBy.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['NPI','Fa Name'])

df['Fa Name'] = df.groupby('NPI')['Fa Name'].ffill()
print (df)
    NPI  Fa Name
1  1100  Johnson
0  1100  Johnson
2  1100  Johnson
4  2222   Meghan
5  2222   Meghan
6  4444      NaN
7  4444      NaN
3  5555      NaN
```